# Rails: form for different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a rails app with a landingpage. On the landingpage, the user can sign up for the app. For login, there is an extra view with an extra controller.

It looks like this:

```
views/landinpage/index.html --> sign up form
views/login/index.html --> login form
```

but I only want to have one controller

```
controllers/login_controller --> create new user from sign up form & check login data
```

so I have to get a connection between the landingpage view and the login_controller.

This is my attempt:

```
<%= form_for @login, :url => { :controller => "login_controller", :action => "create" }, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
```

but it throws a route error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"login_controller", :action=>"create"}
```

I already defined login resources in routes.rb, but it seems that the problem is elsewhere?

```
resources :logins
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
   def new
     ...
   end

   def create
     ...
   end
  ...
 end
```

in your route.rb file write

```
  match '/login/create' => 'logins#create', :as => :create_login
  or
  resources :logins
```

in your console - write - `rake routes` and check your routes

then

```
<%= form_for @login, :url => create_login_path(@login) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly. But i have a question left: I have to create a /login/create view. Can i define a redirect to the landingpage after the user submitted the form by changing the routes?

Comment: after submit form you want to display a create action view page?

Comment: Nope. The user should submit the form on the landingpage. After submitting, the user should not redirect to the "login/create" view but to the landingpage.

Comment: ok. in your create action you can define redirect_to landingpage_path. and define routes for landingpage like --   match '/landingpage' => 'controller-name#action name', :as => :landingpage

Comment: if you don't like messy routes file check @Tigraine's answer below

Comment: Update for Rails 4+:  match '/login/create' => 'logins#create', :as => :create_login, via [get,post]

Answer (score 13):

I think your code should look like this:

```
<%= form_for @login, :url => { :controller => "login", :action => "create" }, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
```

can't test this right now, but I believe the _controller part is not required.

**Update:**

Another thing that I'm using a lot and that works:

```
<%= form_for @login, :url => create_login_path(@login), :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
```

You may have to fix the `create_login_path` part to match your application's routes but that's how I usually define these views.

Comment: unfortunately, it throws: `No route matches {:controller=>"login", :action=>"create"}`

Answer (score 0):

you can see the html form action part, you can see!

your `config/routes` has

```
resources :posts

namespace :admin do
  resources :posts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
   def new
     ...
   end

   def create
     ...
   end
  ...
 end
```

in your **`routes.rb`** file

```
resources :logins do
    collection do
      post :create
    end
  end
```

and in your **`views`**

```
<%= form_for @login, :url => create_login_path(@login) do |f| %>>
```