# Getting the ability to post in a model under a different controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I decided to make a clone of Facebook in Rails. First I'm working on getting status updates working. I got it setup as the `StatusUpdate` model that is called by the `Pages` controller to render on the index page.

The issue I'm having is that if I use `form_for(@status_update)` I get:

```
undefined method to_key' for
<StatusUpdate::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000000049d3448>
Did you mean? to_set to_ary
```

If I use `form_with(model: @status_update)`:

```
undefined method to_model' for
<StatusUpdate::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000000471cd80>
Did you mean? to_xml
```

If I use `form_with(model: status_update)`:

```
undefined local variable or method status_update' for
<#<Class:0x0000000005801678>:0x0000000002ec8ec8>
Did you mean? @status_update
```

My action:

```
def create
  @status_update = StatusUpdate.new(status_update_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @status_update.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Status successfully posted!' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
```

and `erb` view:

```
<%= form_with(model: status_update) do |sp| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= sp.label :status_update %>
    <%= sp.text_area :status_update, class: 'form-control', rows: 15, placeholder: 'Content' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= sp.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: show us your action controller method

Comment: edited hopefully with what your talking about.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13028700/5783745)'s what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the initialisation step. You have to first initialise the model object in `new` action of the controller.

```
def new
 @status_update = StatusUpdate.new
end
```

and then use it in form.

```
form_with(model: @status_update)
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `form_with` must be a single model instance. Not a whole collection.

```
class Pages
  def index
    @status_updates = StatusUpdate.all
    @new_status_update = StatusUpdate.new
  end
end

---
# app/views/pages/index.html.erb
<%= form_with(model:  @new_status_update) %>
  # ...
<% end %>

<%= @status_updates.each do |s| %>
# ...
<% end %>
```

Which is why you need to pay attention to pluralization when naming variables!

Another way to solve this is by using a condition:

```
# app/views/status_updates/form.html.erb 
<%= form_with(model: local_assigns(:status_update) || StatusUpdate.new) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Which lets you use the form as a partial even without a StatusUpdate instance:

```
# app/views/pages/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'status_updates/form' %>

<%= @status_updates.each do |s| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```